# System language (login screen display language) overwrites my user's language set by GNOME Settings after (re)boot

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, language-support, locale, gnome-control-center

**Edit 1:** I'm running Ubuntu GNOME 20.04. I'm trying to set a display language for my user's session different from the system's language (login screen display language) but I've been unsuccessful so far...

System language is Portuguese, my user's language is set to English in **GNOME Settings** but everything is in Portuguese (`locale` reports `pt_BR.UTF-8`). Language packs for both languages are installed.

What can I do?

**Edit 2:** I've just noted that if I log out and log back in, then it starts respecting my language settings. But if I log in for the first time after (re)boot, it will fallback to the system's language again.

**Edit 3:** Here is the output of `locale` as rquested by @Gunnar Hjalmarsson.

After a fresh boot or reboot, both on graphical and console mode:

```
LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

After the second graphical mode login (ex.: boot → login → logout → login), both on graphical and console mode:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

**Note:** I originally had some packages missing and also hit an Ubuntu installation/language system bug, as pointed by @Gunnar Hjalmarsson, so I misunderstood what was happening.

---

### *Original post:* Trying to change the login screen display language (not input) created a language setup mess

Running Ubuntu GNOME 20.04. The series of events, if I recall it right, were these:

1. **Both** my user session and the login screen **were in English**.

   - Both with keyboard input in Portuguese, but I don't think it's relevant for my problem.
2. I tried to set the **login screen** language **to Portuguese** using GNOME Settings.
3. After reboot, the **login screen** was **still in English** and, for my surprise, my **user's session was set to Portuguese**.
4. I tried again with Settings, **set user session back to English** and **set login screen another time to Portuguese**.
5. Rebooted again and the result was *this*...

   - Login screen:

     - still in English
     - GNOME Settings says it's in Portuguese
     - `localectl` says default language is Portuguese (`LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8`)
   - User session:

     - mixed, GNOME Shell and GNOME apps in English, other apps in Portuguese
     - GNOME Settings says it's in English
     - `locale` says it's in Portuguese (`LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8`)

---

#### Questions

How do I fix this mess? Should I use `dpkg-reconfigure`?

Should I install some missing language package? Here is the output of `check-language-support`:

**`en_US` installed**

```
hunspell-en-us language-pack-en language-pack-gnome-en poppler-data wamerican wbritish
```

**`en_US` *not* installed**

```
chromium-browser-l10n firefox-locale-en gimp-help-en
```

**`pt_BR` installed**

```
poppler-data wbrazilian
```

**`pt_BR` *not* installed**

```
chromium-browser-l10n firefox-locale-pt gimp-help-pt gnome-getting-started-docs-pt gnome-user-docs-pt hunspell-pt-br language-pack-gnome-pt language-pack-pt wportuguese
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, to start with, if you want the display language to be in Portuguese, then install the Portuguese language packs.

```
sudo apt install language-pack-pt language-pack-gnome-pt
```

Then reboot and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you. I already did that and it solved partially my problem (see edit in question). It's strange that Portuguese was even listed as an available display language when I just remember installing Portuguese as input method before.

Comment: @leogama: Right, it's unfortunate. You hit [this bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1532519). (I don't see that you edited the question, btw.)

Comment: Hold on, I'm still editing...

Comment: could you take a look at my question edition number 2?

Comment: Please edit your question again and include the full output from the `locale` terminal command.

Comment: There you go, Gunnar. Thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

What solved this issue was to reset my user's session display language back to the system's language and then set it again to my language of choice using **Language Support** (`gnome-language-selector`) instead of **Settings** (`gnome-control-center`).

Any information that help's me to fill up a bug report for GNOME/Debian/Ubuntu is still welcome.

---

**Edit:** I'm not so sure this actually worked. See the question's update.

Comment: Hmm.. _Language Support_ and _Settings_ basically do the same thing. Switching from Portuguese to English using _Settings_ ought to work (at next login). So if you think there is a bug, you'd need to describe step by step how to reproduce it.